# Woocommerce subscriptions API and Authorize.net (Credit Card Payment Failed (Subscription Renewal: payment token is missing/invalid.))

Tags: woocommerce, authorize.net, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-subscriptions

We created a user on authorize.net with the following data:

Customer profile ID : `901961001`

Payment Profile ID: Payment ProfileID: `901782940`

Now on [Woocommerce API](https://woocommerce.github.io/subscriptions-rest-api-docs/index.html#create-a-subscription), we have the following JSON that we try to run to create the subscription:

```
{
  "customer_id": 80595,
  "status": "active",
  "billing_period": "month",
  "billing_interval": 3,
  "start_date": "2021-10-08 19:45:00",
  "next_payment_date":"2021-10-08 19:48:00",
  "payment_method": "authorize_net_cim_credit_card",
  "payment_details":{
    "post_meta": {
      "_wc_authorize_net_cim_credit_card_customer_id":"901961001",
      "_wc_authorize_net_cim_payment_profile_id ": "901782940",
      "_wc_authorize_net_cim_credit_card_payment_token": "901782940"

    }
  },
  "billing": {
    "first_name": "check6",
    "last_name": "check6",
    "address_1": "check6",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "CA",
    "postcode": "94103",
    "country": "US",
    "email": "check6@example.com",
    "phone": "(555) 555-5555"
  },
  "shipping": {
    "first_name": "check6",
    "last_name": "check6",
    "address_1": "check6",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "CA",
    "postcode": "94103",
    "country": "US"
  },
  "line_items": [
    {
      "product_id": 33704,
      "quantity": 3
    }
  ],
  "shipping_lines": [
    {
      "method_id": "flat_rate",
      "method_title": "Flat Rate",
      "total": "10"
    }
  ],
   "meta_data": [
    {
      "key": "_custom_subscription_meta",
      "value": "custom meta"
    }
  ]
}
```

Well.. the subscription does get created BUT when it's time for the renewal we get the following error:
Authorize.Net Credit Card Payment Failed (Subscription Renewal: payment token is missing/invalid.) Order status changed from Pending payment to Failed.

How do we pass the correct payment token thru woocommerce subscriptions api?